# Photoshop is changing text when saving as PDF

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, pdf, export

When making circular text with photoshop CS6, for example: 
Circular written text

[image]

Now, when I want to save my project as PDF the text is getting turned, for example: Turned letters, but the same circular path

[image]

Does anyone know what is going wrong?

Comment: What PDF settings are you using? I tried exporting here with the default settings, everything normal, no distortions. Did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: I have tried this too, and I can't replicate the problem. Have you tried `File` > `Save As` then choose Photoshop PDF as the file type,  then open the PDF in Adobe Reader?  As Luciano has said, perhaps something to do with your pdf settings.

Answer (score 0):

Simple

- Select text layer
- Go to type and convert to shape

Answer (score 0):

You should always, as stated above, convert your text to the shape. It is quite important when working with specific effects or transformation as they might not be supported by the PDF format you're using.

It is even more important if you are using a specific font as you want to be sure that the person you are sending it to can load the thing properly (it is normally not a problem, but I recall my teacher telling us about that one time she had to keep a banner with a bad text, and they had to fix it with paint because it already costed a lot to print in the first place).

Also, I'm wondering why do you want to save a Photoshop file in `.pdf`? Photoshop is made for image editing and you usually output JPEG or PNG with it (I didn't even know that it could save it in PDF until now!), are you sure you don't want to use Illustrator or InDesign instead? It depends on what you're doing in the first place, of course, but just making sure... (I might be wrong but be kind, my first answer ;) )